# Error while trying to broadcast web notification using action cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, actioncable

When I am trying to broadcast a web notification using action cable I am getting below error in rails server terminal

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-08-12 11:40:16 +0530
Processing by PageController#index as HTML
  Rendering page/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered page/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 11.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

2019-08-12 11:40:24 +0530: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
```

And the below error in rails console terminal

```
rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 70237
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:199: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.3)
2.5.1 :001 > ActionCable.server.broadcast 'web_notifications_channel', message: '<p>Hello World </p>'
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to web_notifications_channel: {:message=>"<p>Hello World </p>"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
Redis::ProtocolError ( Got 'H' as initial reply byte. If you're in a forking environment, such as Unicorn, you need to connect to Redis after forking. )
```

Comment: you need to install and configure redis

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: ubuntu or mac??

Comment: I am using mac.

Comment: what is output of `redis-cli ping`?

Comment: It gives `PONG` as output

Comment: What your written in redis.rb file of project?

Comment: I didn't change anything in `redis.rb`. Is there any changes has to be done?

Comment: `development:
  adapter: redis`

`test:
  adapter: redis`

`production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
  channel_prefix: temp`
in cable.yml file

Comment: It was already done

Comment: your redis connection is not working

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: exit and run rails c again. try to restart redis again

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason for this error,
`I didn't specify the correct port`